# Building Gradle application in terminal using wrapper fails

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

When trying to use gradle wrapper to build the app I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'io.freefair.lombok', version: '5.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.freefair.lombok:io.freefair.lombok.gradle.plugin:5.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(repo link)
```

If I try running the applicaiton or running the build task from Intelij's gradle tab everything works fine. I tried clearing cache for gradle and intelij but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your build fails because it is not searching the Gradle Plugin Portal for plugins.

This happens because you are calling `pluginManagement.repositories()` in `settings.gradle` without calling `pluginManagement.repositories.gradlePluginPortal()`. Add this call and your error should be fixed.

This happens because if you add a new plugin repository you need to explicitly specify `gradlePluginPortal()` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories).